# Number of ways to place $60$ people, some of them indistinguishable, into rooms with limited capacity

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve a combinatorics problem, but I don't know if I'm doing it right

> There are three rooms in the office (two on the first floor and one on
> the third). We have $60$ people at work.

Q:

> In how many ways can people be placed, if it matters who is with whom in the room and whether the
> person is on the 1st or 2nd floor. The persons on the first floor are
> indistinguishable. It is known that each room can accommodate $20$
> people.

How I am trying to do it:

I can choose people for the first room in $$A =\binom{60}{20}B =\binom{40}{20} C =\binom{20}{20}$$
I don't know how to proceed

I will be grateful for a detailed explanation
Thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by : "it matters who is with whom in the room"

Comment: I think it means: it is important that person #1 is with person #5 on the same room

Answer (score 1):

The answer is :

$$ \frac{60!}{20! \times 20! \times 20! \times 2!} = 288915607239237911915932950 $$

Explanation :

$$ \frac{\text{ways to arrange 60 people}}{\text{ways to arrange 20 people in each room} \times \text{arrangements of rooms in the first floor}} $$

Consider a general case for the problem:
dividing n people into 3 groups of sizes k1, k2, and k3, considering that the groups are indistinguishable, can be represented mathematically as:

$$ \frac{n!}{k1! \times k2! \times k3! \times (n-k1-k2-k3)! \times (\text{number of groups})!} $$

This equation represents the total number of ways to arrange n people among the 3 groups, divided by the number of ways to arrange the people within each group and the number of ways to arrange the groups themselves.

However, in your case, since the room on the 3rd floor is distinct from the other two, you only need to divide by 2! instead of the number of groups. Therefore, the equation becomes:

$$ \frac{n!}{k1! \times k2! \times k3! \times (n-k1-k2-k3)! \times 2!} $$

I hope that this helps clarify the solution.

Comment: can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Although persons are inherently taken to be distinguishable, if you insist that "The persons on the first floor are indistinguishable" (like 40 cattle, say) then there are 40 "cattle" in the two rooms on the first floor, and 20 people on the second floor.

So there is only **one** way to place the "cattle" on the first floor and the people on the second floor.